# Equivalence of Two Binary Quadratic Forms

Tags: number-theory

Are two binary quadratic forms $f(x,y) = 4x^2 + xy + y^2$ and $g(x,y) = x^2 − 5xy + 10y^2$ equivalent? If so, make the equivalence explicit. If not, explain why not.

I began by finding the discriminant of both forms, and found that it is identical as it is -15 in both forms. How can I go from here to make it explicit?

I was thinking of transforming $f(x,y)$ to $f(px'+qy',rx'+sy')$ to see if that will equal $g(x,y)$, where $ps-qr = 1$.

Comment: You have been around for two years. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: You're right - I corrected it!

Comment: Which is the field you are working with? $\Bbb{R}$? If it is the case, you might want to compute their signature by reducing them.

Comment: Gauss reduction is a step by step thing,  do it for each form.  Pretty easy for binary (positive) forms.  If done correctly: there is one and only one reduced representative in each equivalence class of positive binaries.

Comment: Yes, I am working with the reals. How would I go about reducing them, is there a theorem or hint you could provide?

Comment: Anon, what book or notes are you using?

Comment: from 2014  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017040/minimum-value-of-a-positive-definite-binary-quadratic-form-along-integers

Comment: Number Theory Revealed by Andrew Granville

Answer (score 0):

For quadratic form $a x^2 + bxy + c y^2$   abbreviate as $$  \langle a, \; b, \; c \rangle $$

If $c < a,$ or if $c = a$ and $b<0,$ replace the form (the triple) by
$$ \langle a, \; b, \; c \rangle \mapsto \langle c, \; -b, \; a \rangle $$ (and rename as abc again).

If either $b > a $ or $b \leq -a,$ find the integer $n$ so that $-a < 2an+b \leq a,$ then replace the form by
$$ \langle a, \; \; 2an+b, \; \; an^2 + bn+c \rangle  $$ (and rename as abc again).

By hand, it is often enough to have $n = \pm 1$  at the price of a few more steps. With $n = 1,$
$$ \langle a, \; b, \; c \rangle \mapsto \langle a, \; \; 2a+b, \; \; a + b+c \rangle  $$ (and rename as abc again).

Or with $n = -1,$
$$ \langle a, \; b, \; c \rangle \mapsto \langle a, \; \; b-2a, \; \; a - b+c \rangle  $$ (and rename as abc again).

Keep alternating these steps until the form is "reduced" which means
$$ 1 \leq a \leq c, \; \; \mbox{AND} \; \; \; -a < b \leq a, \; \; \mbox{AND IF} \; \; a=c \; \; \; \mbox{THEN} \; \; b \geq 0 .   $$
Once a form is reduced, the first coefficient (the new $a$ value) is the smallest positive element represented.